# How to find time of day or range in TIMESTAMP column

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have a list of events with begin and end timestamps in GMT UTC+0. The column is type DATE but has time as well (not designed by me).

The begin timestamp is plainly indexed

I need to find events the occur between, say, 06:00 and 22:00 Localtime which is Eastern Daylight Time UTC-4. on any day between March 31th and April 2nd.

The Only way I've found to do it is convert it TO_CHAR() then. It's also not using the index because it's using TO_CHAR function.

Here's what I go so far.

```
  TO_CHAR(e.begin_time,'HH24:MI') >= TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('06:00','HH24:MI'),'US/Eastern') AT TIME ZONE '+00:00','HH24:MI') AND 
  TO_CHAR(e.begin_time,'HH24:MI') <= TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('22:00','HH24:MI'),'US/Eastern') AT TIME ZONE '+00:00','HH24:MI') AND 
  TO_CHAR(e.begin_time,'DDMMYYYY HH24:MI') >= TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('Mar-31-2012 00:00','MON-DD-YYYY HH24:MI'),'US/Eastern') AT TIME ZONE '+00:00','DDMMYYYY HH24:MI') AND 
  TO_CHAR(e.begin_time,'DDMMYYYY HH24:MI') <= TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('Apr-2-2012 23:59','MON-DD-YYYY HH24:MI'),'US/Eastern') AT TIME ZONE '+00:00','DDMMYYYY HH24:MI')
```

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

The performance of the following might not be what's wanted, but if you cast the DATE value to a TIMESTAMP you can use the EXTRACT function in a manner similar to:

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table e
  WHERE e.BEGIN_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('31-MAR-2012 00:00:00',
                                     'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                         AND TO_DATE('02-APR-2012 23:59:59',
                                     'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND
        EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(e.BEGIN_TIME AS TIMESTAMP)) BETWEEN 6 AND 22
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Bob, I had this idea. It looked too messy since I need to do the EXTRACT MINUTE as well. I'll go with this solution if nothing else pops up. But I'm curious, which is Faster: EXTRACT or TO_CHAR?

Comment: I don't know which is faster. My initial guess would be that EXTRACT would be quicker as the database is just working with the binary representation of the TIMESTAMP - but since in this case there's a CAST in there as well, who knows? I would expect that the comparison of date and number values (dates and extracted hours) should be quicker than string comparisons.

Comment: OK, so EXTRACT was faster than TO_CHAR, and now my query looks like this: 

  EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(e.begin_time AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') AS TIMESTAMP)) BETWEEN 6 AND 22 AND
  EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(e.begin_time AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') AS TIMESTAMP)) BETWEEN 0 AND 0

The minutes are 0 because they come from a PHP app. If the user was to choose 6:30 and 22:00, i believe my above clause would also get events at 22:30.

edit: Anyway around this problem? Obviously I don't want 22:30.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to grab data based on a portion of a date field, of course the index will not be used. there just ain't any workaround to that. You could look into adding a function-based index, however, to index on the minutes of the day in EST. Or, perhaps, add a new column to hold minutes_est, have it populated by an insert/update trigger and then base your query on that.

If this is a regularly used query, and the performance of a full table scan isn't cutting it, then yes - I think this is one of those times where you might need to do some redesign based on your needs for this.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that is the best solution if I owned the database. Unfortunately I do not and cannot make changes to it, only query it.